# Table with multiple headers or merged columns Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to build a table in plotly with callback, I am using `Go.Table` but I am unable to create multiple headers

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was correct read [docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#table), you can not create multiple headers.

First possible solution is to move headers to values:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['Version', 'Baseline', 'Promo', 'VDP+']),
    cells=dict(values=[['', '08/20 to 08/27','08/13 to 08/20', '08/06 to 08/13',\
                        '07/30 to 08/06'],
                       ['Current Month: Aug 18', '', '', '', ''],
                       ['Current Month: Aug 18', '', '', '', ''],
                       ['Current Month: Aug 18', '', '', '', '']]))

data = [trace] 
plotly.offline.plot(data, filename = 'basic_table.html')
```

Looks like:

[image: First solution]

But you can not operate with them such as columns what is not great.

Second possible solution is to specify `prefix`(or `suffix` - depends what would you like more):

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['Version', '.Baseline', '.Promo', '.VDP+'], 
                prefix = ['','Current_Month:_Aug_18', 'Current_Month:_Aug_18',\
                          'Current_Month:_Aug_18'],
                ),
    cells=dict(values=[['08/20 to 08/27', '08/13 to 08/20', '08/06 to 08/13', \
                        '07/30 to 08/06'],
                       ['', '', '', ''],
                       ['', '', '', ''],
                       ['', '', '', '']]))

data = [trace] 
plotly.offline.plot(data, filename = 'basic_table.html')
```

And in this case, you can add your columns as prefix or suffix.

Looks like:
[image: second solution]

Update: Yep, you can create an empty row (just do not specify `headers`):
[image: empty row]

Update: Currently I found the way to get what you need:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=[['Version', ''],
                        ['Baseline', 'Current Month: Aug 18'],
                        ['Promo', 'Current Month: Aug 18'],
                        ['VDP+', 'Current Month: Aug 18']]),
    cells=dict(values=[['08/20 to 08/27', '08/13 to 08/20', '08/06 to 08/13', \
                        '07/30 to 08/06'],
                       ['', '', '', ''],
                       ['', '', '', ''],
                       ['', '', '', '']]))

data = [trace] 
plotly.offline.plot(data, filename = 'basic_table.html')
```

Looks like:
[image: This is what you want, is not it?]

I can not [hide](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#table-header-line-width) one line but the whole lines of headers(add `line = dict(width=0)` after headers values):
[image: hmm]
Or set the [color](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#table-header-line-color) of lines but for all the lines again (with same results as above)

Comment: This is helpful, i tried the prefix-suffix way , but the customer is bent on adding headers.

Comment: Also, is there a way to hide a header all together , i get a empty row if I dont pass a header trace. ?

Comment: @saket-dabi, as I correct understand you, you can get empty rows (see updated answer)

Comment: But , as in your case as well, the empty top row (when no header is passed) is still visible. Is there a posibility we can hide it completely ? or remove grid lines from there.

Comment: @saket-dabi, I am updated answer. In plotly you cannot remove one particular line as I know